# Force Windows to trigger scheduled task in Battery Saver mode

Tags: windows-10, scheduled-tasks

I have several scheduled tasks in Windows 10 which usually start by time trigger or by computer startup trigger. These tasks run as SYSTEM account. But when Windows gets into Battery Saver mode all task triggers are delayed until the system exits battery saver mode. This is by design, as written here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/design/component-guidelines/battery-saver

Is there any workaround to force specific scheduled tasks to start even in Battery Saver mode?

Comment: The link actually says that most scheduled tasks will run "Windows task scheduler tasks trigger only if the task is:  * Not set to Start the task only if the computer is idle... (task doesn't use IdleSettings), * Not set to run during automatic maintenance (task doesn't use MaintenanceSettings), * Is set to Run only when user is logged on (task LogonType is TASK_LOGON_INTERACTIVE_TOKEN or TASK_LOGON_GROUP). All other triggers are delayed until the system exits battery saver mode."

Comment: Yes, but my tasks run as SYSTEM, so it does not meet the requirement "Is set to Run only when user is logged on..." and does not trigger in battery saver mode.